# Android: Fb adding privacy not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

While login into FB at that time privacy webview from fb is poped up. After trying to update privacy while posting but not working.

Is there any API I need to call.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
JSONObject privacyObj = new JSONObject();
privacyObj.accumulate("value", "EVERYONE");
params.putString("privacy", privacyObj.toString());

GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/live_videos", params, HttpMethod.POST,
new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

    }
}
);
request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: You can not specify a broader privacy when making the post, than the one the user selected when logging in to the app. (And you can not force a default on the login screen either. The user has to change the selection there, or change it later on in their settings under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)

Comment: @CBroe Same flow works fine in iOS only in android if I try set the privacy while posting it is not working. 

Ok is there any other way I can provide the option to change the privacy from inside of the application. Fb provides any such API's ?

Comment: “Not working” meaning what exactly? Privacy gets ignored? Errors? Assuming that you are using the same app id on iOS and Android, you should be able to use the same privacy level in both; maybe your Android code is not a 100% correct in that regard. // There’s no API to set this, the user must do it in their settings.

Comment: Privacy parameter gets ignored.
During login privacy dialog appears and user selects some option.

I need that privacy dialog option. So user can alter privacy settings before posting into wall.